# How do I Marshal an entire http.Request using an encoder with GoLang?

Tags: go

I have a simple go server...

```
package main

import (
  "net/http"
  "log"
)

func simple(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
  b := []byte("Hello World")
  w.Write(b)
}
func main(){
  http.HandleFunc("/", index)
  log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

Now I want to print out the whole request. I want headers, url, payload, etc. I see in Go this is typically done by using an "encoder" to "marshal" the object but when I try that...

```
import (
  "net/http"
  "log"
  "encoding/json"
)
func simple(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
  e, err := json.Marshal(r)
  if(err != nil){
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
  w.Write(e)
}
```

with the request object I get...

```
json: unsupported type: func() (io.ReadCloser, error)
```

Again this makes sense to me because, although I am new to go, I can understand that this is a function that returns a stream. My question is what do I need to use to get EVERYTHING in the request including headers (SERVER COOKIES). I know I can write a custom Marshaler but I would like to avoid that.

Is there a simple way to marshal an entire http request in go?

Comment: No, there is no simple way to do so. `http.Request` is not made to be marshaled.

Comment: @MuffinTop Thanks for listening and actually providing a solution instead of just criticism. That looks like it might work as part of the solution I am looking for. Feel free to post it as an answer and I will +1 it

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in the body and the headers, you can get them this way:

```golang
package main

import (
  "fmt"
 "net/http"
 "strings"
 "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {
  body := `{"foo": "bar"}`
  req, _ := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, "http://my.url", strings.NewReader(body))
  req.Header.Add("my-header-key", "my-header-value")
  req.AddCookie(&http.Cookie{Name: "my-cookie", Value: "cookie-value"})

  fmt.Println("body:")
  reqBody, _ := req.GetBody()
  readReqBody, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(reqBody)
  fmt.Println(string(readReqBody))
  fmt.Println()

  fmt.Println("cookies:")
  for name, value := range req.Header {
    fmt.Println(name, value)
  }
}
```

This should print this:

```
body:
{"foo": "bar"}

cookies:
My-Header-Key [my-header-value]
Cookie [my-cookie=cookie-value]
```

Comment: Thank you that is a great implementation. However, does this mean the answer here is you need to roll your own?

Comment: Of course you have to roll your own, or possible find one written based on the same requirements. There is no universal schema for representing the http protocol in json.

Comment: It doesn't have to be in JSON, I could reencode it. Seems weird that it doesn't provide a utility function.